# My loader doesn't calls complete event in Actionscript 3

Tags: actionscript-3, event-handling, bulkloader

In my flash & actionscript app, Bulk-Loader doesn't dispatch complete event. My load elements:

```
private var yukleyici:BulkLoader = new BulkLoader("yukleyicii");

yukleyici.add("mouse_simge.png", {id:"mouseSimge"});
yukleyici.add("para_ikon.png", {id:"paraikon"});
yukleyici.add("arkp_puan.png", {id:"arkpPuan"});
yukleyici.add("fav2.png", {id:"tecrube"});
yukleyici.add("muzik_arkaplan.mp3", {id:"muzik"});
yukleyici.add("logo.png", {id:"logoo"});
yukleyici.add(Facebook.getImageUrl(String(uidvar), "large"), {id:"profilfoto", type:BulkLoader.TYPE_IMAGE, context:context1});

yukleyici.addEventListener(BulkLoader.COMPLETE, completeHandler);
yukleyici.start();
```

But this code doesn't fire up my **completeHandler** function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably set an [error handler too](http://code.google.com/p/bulk-loader/wiki/GettingStarted#Listening_for_events:), to see what really happens, you're only hooking up the handler for successful loading.

```
yukleyici.addEventListener(BulkLoader.ERROR, onAllError);
```